# Writing sqlilte query for first converting dateString to date and performing a match with current date

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In my database table I have a column where **date** is stored as a **string**. Format is Jan 29, 2017. Now I want to retrieve all the row data of this table where current date is greater than the date stored. I should be first converting this column dateString to actual NSDate and then making a comparison with the current date, thereby retrieving all the row data. But I am getting no clue as to how actually write the query. Any help would be much appreciated.
I am using sqlite.

Comment: you need to convert stringDate to NSDate after retrieving data from sqlite?

Comment: better store date as DateTime format, and You can compare directly

Comment: What's the point of conversion after data has been retrieved. First I have to match the dates and then retrieve only the data which match the above said criterion.

Comment: @larva u suggestion is right but now I am almost halfway through the project and  wil hav 2 make several other changes

Comment: @mars It's a little work now but it will make your life so much easier if you store your dates properly. Never store dates as strings except maybe as "yyyyMMdd" (which is at least sortable and comparable).

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5252/data-types/18688/date-time-types).

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, u r right. Finally ended up by saving dates using 'timeIntervalSince1970'. By the way, Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

the best ways is save date string in SQlite time String format ex `YYYY-MM-DD` so You can compare datetime directly.

Here is sqlite query in your case(I did test in terminal)

```
create table TestData (rowID integer, date_string varchar(10));
insert into TestData values(0, 'Jan 27, 2017');
insert into TestData values(1, 'Jan 28, 2017');
insert into TestData values(2, 'Feb 10, 2017');
insert into TestData values(3, 'Feb 12, 2017');
insert into TestData values(4, 'Feb 13, 2017');
insert into TestData values(5, 'Aug 20, 2016');
insert into TestData values(6, 'Aug 21, 2017');
insert into TestData values(7, 'Aug 22, 2017');
```

when I select all

```
select * from TestData;
0|Jan 27, 2017
1|Jan 28, 2017
2|Feb 10, 2017
3|Feb 12, 2017
4|Feb 13, 2017
5|Aug 20, 2017
6|Aug 21, 2017
7|Aug 22, 2017
```

And here is query you need when I get all row with `date >= '20170210'`

```
select rowID,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(date_string, 'Jan', '01'), 'Feb', '02'), 'Mar', '03'), 'Apr', '04'), 'May', '05'), 'Jun', '06'), 'Jul', '07'), 'Aug', '08'), 'Sep', '09'), 'Oct', '10'), 'Nov', '11'), 'Dec', '12') as date_time_string 
from TestData 
where substr(date_time_string, 8)||substr(date_time_string, 1, 2)||substr(date_time_string, 4, 3) >= '20170210';

2|02 10, 2017
3|02 12, 2017
4|02 13, 2017
6|08 21, 2017
7|08 22, 2017
```

It seem to be bad way, hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to perform below conversion of date formatter and than retrive your data with query :

```
//First You have to formate your date in your string date formate.
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"];
NSString *currentDate=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

//Your Query 
NSString *fetchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE date < '%@'",currentDate];
```

**Edit:**

**Look at this Screen shot:**

[image]

**Link :** https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

If you want string date comparison you need to follow date formate of `SQLite` that and than `SQLite` **< & >** function works with this query.

So just do one thing where you are inserting data change formate of date and insert data into DB and than every thing works as expected.

Hope this will helps you to get proper data.

Comment: This returns wrong entries like 'Jan 14, 2016', 'Jan 23, 2017'......etc. when searched for 'Dec 27, 2017'. May be because string is being compared here rather than actual dates.

Comment: You can't compare dates as strings in this format. The name of the month will be compared alphabetically. And it doesn't deal with different languages.

Comment: Your update won't work either because the dates in the database are stored as strings in an uncomparable format.